# Best approach for implementing token based authentication in mobile application client [ios]

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, authentication, oauth-2.0

What is the best approach for implementing the **token based authentication** mechanism?

**What I have tried**

1. I have used the ***traditional http call mechanism*** for getting
   access token store in user-defaults and called in the later
   web-service
2. Another one I tried is the ***AFNetworking, AFOauthClient
   mechanism*** where I created the client and get the token set it in
   the header of the shared instance and using it over the code

I find the **2nd** method the proper way for implementing this.But the refresh mechanism handling is a mess.How to implement it in a proper manner?